# How do I trim the bottom of an image?

Tags: css, image, formatting

I'm trying to cut off the bottom of a image so the next row of images an fit. I've tried to trim the bottom but it hasn't worked. I want to bottom edge to be in line with the image next to it.

Here is the current page: [My Page](https://enzobarrett.github.io/enzowebsite/index.html)

```
img.left {
 padding: 0 12px 0 0;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
width: 33.33%;
 }`
```

What it currently looks like

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: post your code !! we can't help without seeing your draft!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the images into a div and control the size of that div with height, width and overflow attributes in css. A bit like this;

```
<div class="control" style="height: 600px;overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
    <img class="big" src="images/35473299826_50c6ced1ec_k.jpg" alt="boy 
     with ferry">
    <img class="right" src="images/34628953174_408fac96c3_z.jpg" 
     alt="flowers">
    <img class="left" src="images/34702862403_ddf655f873_z.jpg" alt="One of 
     my pictures">
</div>
```

The output looks like this for me; [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym4oG.jpg)

Comment: How are you getting this to work? It's not doing anything for me. Are you putting something in the css file.

Comment: No css file just the css you see on the div class. You could try adding the control class to your css file and then adding the styles into that. The basis of it is that you need to just wrap the images so then you can manipulate their height and widths :)

Comment: I can see that you added the control class, I made the height 800px on your site and it worked for me, you may need to adjust the height